# Appending select options - IE problem/solution cause other browser issues

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, select, innerhtml

I have a `<select>` that depending on previous options is populated by a var with a bunch of `<option>` values.

Naturally, because IE doesn't work with innerHTML I have to append this template to the `<select>` which now works great in IE. HOWEVER I now need a way to clear out the select options from the previous search and in FF stop it from dropping down to the last `<option>` in the list.

Comment: *I have a that depending on previous options is populated by a var with a bunch of values.* -- that "sentence" is undecipherable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well using YUI3:

```
    node.setContent(template); //removes old children, sets new template as content.
    node.set('selectedIndex', 0); //forces FF to select the first one
```

*Edited with correct methods.*

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite the entire select block using innerHTML, that always works.

Answer (score 1):

Foolproof way of clearing out the options from a `<select>`:

```
while( select_control.length > 0 )
     select_control.options[0] = null
```

Some browsers will clear the list if you do `select_control.length = 0` but I've found this unreliable.

Foolproof way of inserting option:

```
var new_option = new Option(text, value)
try {
    select_control.add(new_option, select_control.options[0])
} catch(e) {
    select_control.add(new_option, 0)
}
```

The `0` is the index of the item you want your item before. To add it to the end, do this instead:

```
select_control.options[select_control.length] = new_option
```

This will also work if you want to *replace* a specific item, by specifying the index of an existing option.

Comment: That's some good information, however I found that running new Option 100 times in a loop locks IE up on some computers.

Comment: Okay, I hadn't encountered that bug! I normally only want to add one or two. If I have a whole list to repopulate, I would instead normally render each list and fiddle with the CSS `display` attribute to just show the correct one. (Of course, the server side has to know to look at the correct form element, too.)